# HTTP 415 Unsupported Media Type client when sending data to server

Tags: python, rest, python-requests

Is it that my server is not supporting this request or I am sending some wrong data which doesn't seem to be the case.

```
# importing the requests library
import requests

# defining the api-endpoint
API_ENDPOINT = "http://10.176.14.170:5000/api/du/v1"

# data to be sent to api
data = {"name":"du1"}

# sending post request and saving response as response object
r = requests.post(url = API_ENDPOINT, data = data)

print(r)
```

Response:

```
<Response [415]>
```

Success from a web CLI that is running on same server.

```
post /api/du/v1

POST api/du/v1 {"name":"du1"}
```

I also get success when I send the POST request using `curl` command from same server

Comment: Which REST API are you using?

Answer (score 0):

While the original `curl` command was not included, though it was stated that the data was sent via `POST` to the server as is.  I am going to assume that the `curl -d '{"name":"du1"}'` was used along with the appropriate headers being sent.  Now to demonstrate this, the following command is used:

```
$ curl http://httpbin.org/post -d '{"name":"du1"}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json'
{
  "args": {}, 
  "data": "{\"name\": \"du1\"}", 
  "files": {}, 
  "form": {}, 
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "*/*", 
    "Content-Length": "15", 
    "Content-Type": "application/json", 
    "Host": "httpbin.org", 
    "User-Agent": "curl/7.61.0"
  }, 
  "json": {
    "name": "du1"
  }, 
  "url": "http://httpbin.org/post"
}
```

Note the bolded data key - that's what likely was being read by your application.  On the contrary, doing the same thing as done with the provided usage of `requests` at the same endpoint:

```
>>> import requests
>>> r = requests.post('http://httpbin.org/post', data={"name":"du1"})
>>> print(r.text)
{
  "args": {}, 
  "data": "",
  "files": {}, 
  "form": {
    "name": "du1"
  }, 
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "*/*", 
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate", 
    "Content-Length": "8", 
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", 
    "Host": "httpbin.org", 
    "User-Agent": "python-requests/2.21.0"
  }, 
  "json": null, 
  "url": "http://httpbin.org/post"
}
```

Note how the requests had been decoded into a form simply because a) the data submitted was a raw dictionary, and not a JSON encoded string and b) the header was not supplied.  To fix this, simply encode the data and supply the appropriate headers:

```
>>> import requests
>>> import json
>>> data = json.dumps({"name":"du1"})
>>> r = requests.post(
...     'http://httpbin.org/post', data=data,
...     headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
>>> print(r.text)
{
  "args": {}, 
  "data": "{\"name\": \"du1\"}", 
  "files": {}, 
  "form": {}, 
  ...
  "json": {
    "name": "du1"
  }, 
  ...
}
```

Note that the server is now able to interpret the provided data, and can decode that as JSON.